# jqplot zoom function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I want to visualize some timeseries data in the browser with jqplot. My problem is, that the x-axis values overlay and aren't readable.

Therefore, the zoom function would be very useful. But it doesn't work.

Please have a look at the fiddle, it doesn't run on firefox, just on google chrome:

http://jsbin.com/onufih/9/edit

Here's my code:

```
function getTicks() {

    var ticks = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var dateStr = item[0];
        ticks.push(dateStr);
    }

    return ticks;
}

var overviewChart = $.jqplot('overviewChart', [data], {
    title: 'Rotated Axis Text',
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            ticks: getTicks(),
            tickOptions: {

                formatString: '%#m/%#d/%y - %#H h - %#M m - %#S s',
                fontSize: '10pt',
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                angle: -40
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            rendererOptions: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            tickOptions: {
                fontSize: '10pt',
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                angle: 30
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        lineWidth: 4,
        markerOptions: {
            style: 'square'
        }
    }],
    cursor: {
        zoom: true,
        looseZoom: true
    }
});
```

}

Comment: In my opinion, it is not possible with jqPlot. Check this flot example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/index.html It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add show: true to your cursor, as in [this example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you have specified the "ticks" option.  I'm having the same issue.  Seems to me this should work as expected even when I set the ticks (as an initial "un-zoomed" value).